# -bash: ./java: Permission denied

Tags: bash, permissions, java

I'm trying to run Java on my web server (that is only rented). I downloaded the JRE from java.com and unpacked it in a local folder in my home directory.

I changed the permissions of the `bin/java` executable to be able to execute it. The permissions currently are `-rwxrwxrwx` on the file. So basically `777` just to be sure that the permissions are correct.

But if I want to execute it I always get the following error: `-bash: ./java: Permission denied`

Is there any chance to get Java running? Is the provider able to disallow the user to run any executables in his home directory?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what is the mount option for the device that the `home` is in. Please use `df --output=source /some/path/bin/java` to find the device. and then `mount | grep 'DEVICE name from previouse command'` and update the question with the mount options.

Comment: I cannot run `df`, I also get permission denied there ..

Answer (score 3):

> So basically 777 just to be sure that the permissions are correct.

There is so much wrong with that phrase... 777 are -almost always- the *wrong* permissions. 777 would let anyone execute the program, but 755 would have worked perfectly as well.

> Is the provider able to disallow the user to run any executables in his home directory?

Yes. If they mount the home directories with `noexec` flag they can produce the behavior you are seeing (mount command may show you the mount flags, if you're not too constrained).

You may be able to work around it with a command such `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 bin/java`

It's also possible that the permission denied is for one of the libraries your java binary depends on.

Comment: I'm not sure which of the listet mounts is my home drive, but there is one with a `noexec` flag. Your workaround doen't work either. Damn.

Comment: So I may have to ask the provider if there's any chance to get Java running on my server?

Comment: You may want to check first with something simpler, like `cp -v /bin/true .; ./true` but yes, you may need to ask the provider. They will probably install it on the system from the package repositories. I wonder why you need a local java program on your web server, though.

Comment: `-bash: ./true: Permission denied`

Comment: Seems your home is indeed `noexec`

Comment: I'm running a platform that is selling photos of sports photographs, and they need so be processed, watermarked etc. and I have a few Java programs that are doing exactly that. I don't want to redevelope everything in PHP or any other language ..